# Does IO device (HDD like example) work without CPU?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, file-io, operating-system

When I perform an IO operation asynchronously, my application thread will not be blocked.

Like example, this operation :

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("...", ..., ..., ..., 4096, FileOptions.Asynchronous);
await fs.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

I know, a caller thread will call Write API with OVERLAPPED structure. So, when thread gives the IRP to IO manager, he will be released for other work.

But, i can't find any information, that describe work of device like i need.:

1. I want to know, when device work on my async IO operation, does the CPU or some thread work with device?
2. Maybe some thread or CPU controll the device for execution?
3. Or, device just need a commands, which it should to do and device can do it without CPU and threads? If someone know, please describe the device and CPU interaction. I want to know, when CPU and threads doesn't needs for device, if that real.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once the CPU determines the data must be retrieved from storage (i.e. is not located in an operating system managed memory cache), it is largely uninvolved in data transfer from disk to memory with modern hardware.

It provides information about what part of the disk is desired and specifies an address in RAM where the data should go. Hardware external to the CPU then performs the read and places the data in memory using Direct Memory Access ([DMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access)). The underlying hardware signals the CPU when the memory is available to be read.

Prior to the advent of DMA, the CPU was typically involved in (and in some cases, 100% occupied by) disk-to-memory data transfer.

Comment: Eric, it means, that all async operations on Win API level, like work with hdd or network card, emplies using DMA by devices? 

Does exist some indicator, that device can use DMA? And if DMA is not available, that means, async operation will need thread or CPU for work with device?

Comment: I can't think of any device plugged into a modern system bus that doesn't support DMA. It's been around since at least the original PC/XT. Prior to DMA, the CPU was responsible for transferring between devices and memory. If there were such a device out there today (improbable), it would have to work the same way.

Comment: Eric, thank for that information, it very help me. I have a few questions more. Device use DMA by default or need some flag for activate this module? Do you know books where the work of cpu and hdd is described point by point (with DMA and without)? 
Like : 
1. The programm called ReadAPI 
2. IO Manager created IRP package
3. IO Manager choose device
4. IRP package queued to device work
5. CPU set settings for reading
4. CPU wait's the first offsets bytes.
5. CPU transfer first offsets bytes to the memory.
6. CPU wait's the second offsets bytes.
And so on..
Thanks a lot...

Comment: Devices designed for DMA always use it. I'm not aware of books covering non-DMA devices since we're talking about the 1970s and earlier. I can't help with the other questions.